# Wordpress network and sites on subdomains

Tags: wordpress

If you have a wordpress installation on site.com and want to utilise the multisite-functionality for sites on one.site.com, two.site.com etc. but don't want site.com to be included in the network.

I.e. to have the network on e.g. zero.site.com. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Install the network at zero.site.com; use symlinks to direct one.site.com to zero.site.com; and then use the domain mapping plugin to achieve the one.site.com URL.